# gxt align image with combobox

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a loading.gif image that I need to align with a combobox

```
<container:VerticalLayoutContainer addStyleNames="{mystyle}">
    <form:FieldLabel text="{constants.typ}" labelAlign="TOP">
        <form:widget>
            <form:ComboBox ui:field="type" width="300" allowBlank="true" forceSelection="true" triggerAction="ALL" />
        </form:widget>
    </form:FieldLabel>
    <g:Image resource="{loadingGif}" ui:field="Monimage" />
</container:VerticalLayoutContainer>
```

On my view, I have a liststore for my datas.
I have tried to put my image inside the `<form:widget>` but it start an exception that say that I can only have one element per ui:child.

With this code, my image is under the combobox, and I need it to be on it's right side.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the uiBinder parser sees `<form:widget>`, it tries to call method `FieldLabel#setWidget(theComponentUnderTheTag)`.

That's why it does not make sense to have more than one element under the `<form:widget>` tag.

When I cannot do what I want with GWT, I fallback to some plain old HTML. With uiBinder, you can achieve this with a [HTMLPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html):

```
<container:VerticalLayoutContainer addStyleNames="{mystyle}">
  <form:FieldLabel text="{constants.typ}" labelAlign="TOP">
    <form:widget>

      <g:HTMLPanel>
      <!--
        Here, I can now place plain old HTML :) 
        Let's place the 2 components via 2 divs and a float:left.
      -->
        <div style="float:left">
          <form:ComboBox ui:field="type" width="300" allowBlank="true" forceSelection="true" triggerAction="ALL" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <g:Image resource="{loadingGif}" ui:field="Monimage" />                                          
        </div>
      </g:HTMLPanel>

    </form:widget>
  </form:FieldLabel>
</container:VerticalLayoutContainer>
```

If you don't want to use HTML Panel, you can put both elements in the `<form:widget>` tag.

But to achieve this,  you need to wrap them in one component (for example, an [HorizontalPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HorizontalPanel.html)) because you can place only one widget under `<form:widget>`.

```
<form:FieldLabel text="{constants.typ}" labelAlign="TOP">
    <form:widget>
        <g:HorizontalPanel>
          <g:ComboBox ui:field="type" width="300" allowBlank="true" forceSelection="true" triggerAction="ALL" />
          <g:Image resource="{loadingGif}" ui:field="Monimage" />
        </g:HorizontalPanel>
    </form:widget>
</form:FieldLabel>
```

Comment: Everything you wrote work fine thank you. I have tried both and I prefer the HTML panel, because I can have more control over my elements.